# Azure Application Insights on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been attempting to research this issue, but it's difficult since AWS also has a feature called Application Insights, so Google is not as helpful as normal. I saw that there is a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020484/application-insights-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk) regarding something similar, but the OP seems to already be a few steps ahead of where I'm at.

I have an ASP.NET application that I currently run on an EC2 instance, and I can install Application Insights on IIS, but I can't find out how to install Application Insights on the EB instance, since I can't get into the UI, and Application Insights doesn't seem to have a .msi that I can use to install...so what do I do here?

Or am I restricted to implementing this in code only?

Answer (score 1):

(don't have much knowledge about Elastic Beanstalk; I'm from Azure Monitor Application Insights team)

One option is to do it through code - instrument and app with Application Insights SDK.

Another option is to install [Application Insights Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-overview). The latter allows autoinstrument apps running on IIS. This will not work if Elastc Beanstalk doesn't use IIS.